# Gnuplot misreads time data

Tags: gnuplot

I can't seem to get gnuplot to properly plot my time data. (I'm using version 4.6, patchlevel 3.)

For an MWE (well, non-working...), the input file

```
reset

set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"

plot '-' using ($1):($2) with lines lw 3
15:36:12  1.0
15:43:17  3.0
16:12:02  2.0
e
```

produces the following output:
[image]

Apparently, gnuplot interprets the hours as seconds and ignores the rest. I have tried a bunch of other format strings (also single/double quotes), but gnuplot seems to ignore everything except the first number.

Is something wrong with my format, or is this a bug, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `$1` you explicitely select the *numerical* value of the first column, which bypasses any gnuplot automatism to interpret the column values as appropriate (as time value in your case). Simply use `using 1:2`:

```
reset
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"

plot '-' using 1:2 with lines lw 3
15:36:12  1.0
15:43:17  3.0
16:12:02  2.0
e
```

Use the syntax `$1` only when doing calculations with the actual numerical value in the respective column. `$1` is a shortcut for `column(1)`, gnuplot also knows `stringcolumn(1)` and `timecolumn(1)` for other purposes.