# Gnuplot: Ploting with time column

Tags: range, gnuplot, warnings

Hi everyone ;)

i´m trying to plot following file.

```
GAMA LOG TYPE: G-250 H D;
01-08-2017 14:20:16;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:18;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:20;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:22;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:24;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:26;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:28;1377;34;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:30;1377;35;33;34;33;32;
01-08-2017 14:20:32;1377;35;33;34;33;33;
01-08-2017 14:20:34;1377;35;33;34;33;33;
01-08-2017 14:20:36;1377;35;33;34;33;33;
01-08-2017 14:20:38;1377;35;33;34;33;33;
01-08-2017 14:20:40;1378;35;33;34;33;33;
01-08-2017 14:20:42;1378;35;33;34;33;33;
```

Here is my code

```
reset
unset multiplot
set datafile separator ";"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
set xtics timedate
set xtics format "%H:%M:%S"
plot file  u ($1):($3) skip 1 w l lt 1 lc rgb "red"
```

Gnuplot brings following warning

```
Warning: empty x range [3:3], adjusting to [2.97:3.03]
```

Sometimes i put

```
set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y"
```

before

```
set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

because i saw it in other questions, but it doenst work neither!

PS: I tried with gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 6 and gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6

It will be nice if someone can help me!

Comment: Use `plot file u 1:3`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43180732/2604213

Comment: thank you Christoph. It solves my problem!